# React useEffect await data from hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

I am trying to assign `stripeId` for a customer as the account is created using Google Firebase auth with the phone. After this, I redirect the user to a page to enter the credit card details. The issue is that the `stripeId` does not react the useEffect hook on a page. How should I handle this?

```js
const { authUser, loading } = useAuthUserContext();

const {
        email = '',
        displayName = '',
        stripeId = ''
    } = authUser || {};


useEffect(() => {
        if (authUser) {
            const {
                stripeId = ''
            } = authUser;

            if (stripeId) {
                fetch('/api/setup_intent', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ customerId: stripeId })
                })
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
            }
        }
    }, [authUser, loading, stripeId]);
```

Hook

```js
const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null);

const authStateChanged = async (authState: any) => {
        if (!authState) {
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }

        setLoading(true);

        const formattedUser = formatAuthUser(authState);

        setAuthUser(formattedUser);

        const { uid } = authState;

        const docRef = doc(firestore, 'users', uid);
        const snap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (snap.exists()) {
            setAuthUser((f: any) => ({ ...f, ...snap.data() }));
        }

        setLoading(false);
    };
```

Possible fix:

```js
onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
            if (doc.exists()) {
                setAuthUser((f: any) => ({ ...f, ...doc.data() }));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this the incorrect use of the `useEffect` hook, or is it related to `await getDoc` instead of `collection`? I need to somehow "force" the `useEffect` hook to wait for the stripeId, and then re-send the request to the server in the `fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
const { authUser, loading } = useAuthUserContext();

useEffect(() => {
        if (authUser) {
            const {stripeId} = authUser;

            if (stripeId) {
                fetch('/api/setup_intent', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ customerId: stripeId })
                })
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
            }
        }
    }, [authUser, loading]);
```

I think its a bit simpler only having the `authUser` as a dependency in the `useEffect`, and destructuring the value `stripeId` inside the function.

Since `stripeId` is inside `authUser`, changing the `stripeId` of a user will mean that the `authUser` has changed, which in turn will trigger a re-render and call `useEffect`.
**Assuming that `authUser` is stored in state.**

EDIT:
I think I see what you are saying. Possibly the issue is that when you redirect the user to credit-card page, once they add their card, the user isn't updated locally.

As a simplified example, if you had a function that updates a certain field, like 'name', you want to make sure that its updated locally in your `AuthContext`.

So if you had some page to update name, you could do something like this:

```
const [updatedName, setUpdatedName] = useState<string>();
const {authUser, setAuthUser} = useAuthContext();

const handleUpdateName = () => {
  firebaseUpdateName(updatedName); // -> function that updates the name remotely
  setAuthUser({...authUser, name: updatedName }); // -> update the user locally in React
}

...
```

Edit 2:
Sorry I assumed `stripeId` is generated locally - `useSnapshot` is useful for listening to updates, just unsubscribe listener once you have the stripeId.

The docs describe [how to detach a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener), but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it in this case.

Maybe something like this - inside your AuthContext:

```
const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState<User>();
  
  const unsubRef = useRef();

// everytime authuser is changed, this code will be executed - ubsub function is called if the stripeId is present
  if(!!authUser.stripeId && unsubRef.current) {
    unsubRef.current();
  }

  const authStateChanged = async (authState: any) => {
    if (!authState) {
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    const formattedUser = formatAuthUser(authState);
    setAuthUser(formattedUser);

    const { uid } = authState;

    const docRef = doc(firestore, "users", uid);
    const snap = await getDoc(docRef);

    unsub.current = onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
      if (doc.exists()) {
        setAuthUser((f: any) => ({ ...f, ...doc.data() }));
      }
    }); // set unsubscribe function to ref

    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Alternitavely you could generate the stripeId as a GUID locally and POST it to firebase.

Comment: do you mean completely get rid of destructuring from `authUser` outside `useEffect`?

Comment: added changes to the code to show what is `authUser`

Comment: did not help though :c

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. Are you saying that updating `stripId` doesn't cause `useEffect` to run?

Comment: the value coming from hook is still undefined :c

Comment: but it all starts to work as i reload the page, or add changes to the code and save

Comment: the issue here looks as the firebase call returns undefined for some reason, while the uid exists in `formattedUser`:
`
const docRef = doc(firestore, 'users', uid);
const snap = await getDoc(docRef);
`

Comment: in the hook, inside `if (snap.exists())` call, what does `console.log(snap.data())` look like? does it have the stripId?

Comment: it is undefined

Comment: But it is not undefined on a page reload or adding changes to the codebase

Comment: could you make a small app that reproduces the problem and link github or codesandbox? This seems like a tricky thing, it's a bit difficult to figure out what the issue could be without playing around with the code

Comment: i have added a "Possible fix", which looks to solve the issue. what are your thoughts?

Comment: If it works then thats awesome! Since onSnapshot listens to changes, and if it works, that just means that maybe you were missing a refetch the user -  once snapId is added (presumably after the user adds a credit card), maybe you could have called `onAuthStateChanged` and it would have fetched the updated user (or otherwise trigger a re-fetch) from firebase?

Comment: So once the user enters credit card data, and its saved in firebase, you could also update your local authUser object and set its stripeId field or just fetch the new updated user from firebase.

Comment: Would you share an example of this? Because the undefined issue comes from the `await getDoc` function, but it does fetch the data on page reload

Comment: Also, is the `onSnapshot` bad in terms of resource efficiency?

Comment: I think onSnapshot is worse for efficiency - every time the doc is updated, you fetch the data again, which therefore costs more.

Comment: i need to get the stripeId before the user will enter the credit card data, as i need the stripeId to initialize the updateintent. therefore, i have created a firebase function which assigns the stripe ID to the user in firestore after the user authenticates with a phone

Comment: it is really important to note that all works on page reload, it just doesn't work when the user gets created, meaning i have to reload the page. are there ways i can just wait till i get the data from `getDoc`?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad I assumed that stripeId is generated locally.  `onSnapshot` is useful for listening for updates - just make sure to unsubscribe once you get the stripeId so that you're not charge more

Comment: how would i do that? like with `.then()`?